# Installing latex compiler

Tags: apt, updates, latex

I was trying to istall MiKTeX on my Ubuntu 16.04 (32bit). But following error appears on screen. I have only limited knowledge about such distributions. How can this be solved? Please help me.

```
akhil@akhil-G31T-M9:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
[sudo] password for akhil: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for akhil: 
Executing: /tmp/tmp.LK50NQI2bb/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv-keys
D6BC243565B2087BC3F897C9277A7293F59E4889
gpg: requesting key F59E4889 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key F59E4889: public key "MiKTeX Packager <packager@miktex.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
akhil@akhil-G31T-M9:~$ echo "deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/miktex.list
deb http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial universe
akhil@akhil-G31T-M9:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Get:3 https://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/setup/deb xenial InRelease [2,034 B]
Fetched 2,034 B in 10s (195 B/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://miktex.org/download/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
akhil@akhil-G31T-M9:~$ sudo apt-get install miktex
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package miktex
```

Comment: Go for `sudo apt-get install texlive`. This will install latex for you without issues, because it is software supported by the distribution. Look in Software for possible graphical tools to edit latex in as far as you need them.

Comment: According to [MiKTeX requirement page](https://miktex.org/kb/prerequisites), only OS 64 bits are suppported

Comment: @ACA did you success to install MiKTeX? If yes, please write an answer (or tick the good answer as *Accepted*); if not, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1191773/edit) your question to explain what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MiKTeX requirement page](https://miktex.org/kb/prerequisites), only OS 64 bits are suppported.

But after reading a little the *How to build MiKTeX source*, it seems possible to install it on OS 32 bits. Before trying to build, check if you have following requirements :

- C/C++ compiler (there is `gcc` by default on Ubuntu)
- `cmake` (install it using `sudo apt install cmake`)
- `cat`, `fop`, `sed` and `xsltproc` commands
- some libraries :

  - apr
  - aprutil
  - bzip2
  - cairo
  - expat
  - fontconfig
  - freetype2
  - fribidi
  - gd
  - gmp
  - graphite2
  - harfbuzz-icu
  - hunspell
  - icu
  - jpeg
  - log4cxx
  - lzma
  - mpfr
  - mspack
  - LibreSSL (or OpenSSL)
  - pixman
  - png
  - poppler
  - popt
  - potrace
  - uriparser
  - zzip
  - poppler-qt5 (When building UI components with Qt5)

Now, you're ready with all requirements, time to install MiKTeX.

1. Download MiKTeX source code :

   ```
   wget https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/
   ```
2. Build the code outside of source code directory (to keep a backup incase) :

   ```
   mkdir ../source && cmake ../source
   ```

where `../source` is a directory which would contains built source code.

3. Defined build variables (optionnal):

   - If you don't want to install MiKTeX as a standard package (not inside `/usr/lib`, but for example inside `/opt/miktex`):

     ```
     cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/miktex
     ```
   - If you want to build UI applications (this part is still experimental) :

     ```
     cmake -DWITH_UI_QT=ON
     ```
4. Time to build and install MiKTeX :

   ```
   make
   make install
   ```
5. Now, you have to do some initialisations :

   ```
   mpm --admin --update-db
   ```

   `--admin` isn't required if you had install MiKTeX inside your `/home` directory (would be the same for all others command below).

   ```
   initexmf --admin --set-config-value [MPM]AutoInstall=1
   initexmf --admin --update-fndb
   ```

   If you want to shorten MiKTeX executable names (e.g for pdfTeX, default executable name is `miktex-pdftex` and would be shorten as `pdftex`), use the following command (optionnal) :

   ```
   initexmf --admin --mklinks
   ```
6. Installing basic packages :

   ```
   mpm --admin --verbose --package-level=basic --upgrade
   initexmf --admin --mkmaps
   ```
7. Finalize the installation by updating the database, and remove a useless folder created for the installation :

   ```
   initexmf --admin --update-fndb
   rm -fr ~/.miktex
   ```

Source : https://miktex.org/howto/build-unx

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Miktex didn't work on my computer. Then I installed Gummy latex software. It lacks many features, still it works fine on my computer. Why I am so late to reply was I couldn't understand the codes you have mentioned. I tried them on terminal, but as I mentioned in my post I have very little knowledge on such processes. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: You must had ask how it works, I would had explain it to you; which part(s) didn't you understand?